# concatenating char's into a string

Tags: java

I have this method which takes a BigInteger, makes another BigInteger (via rsa algorithm) then thats converted to binary, then thats broken up into blocks of 8 where i get the ascii value for that binary string.

ALL OF THAT WORKS

but im having trouble getting the ascii chars that i get from each binary string and making a new string out of them. Im trying to use the concat method built in but it doesnt seem to be working!

```
    public static String Decrypt( BigInteger ct, BigInteger d, BigInteger mod ){

    String pt = null;
    BigInteger message = ct.modPow(d, mod);     //the decrypted message M but still in BigInteger form
    String plaintext = message.toString(2);

    if( plaintext.length() % 8 != 0 ){
        plaintext = "00000000".substring( plaintext.length() % 8 ) + plaintext;
    }

    String c;
    int charCode = 0;
    for( int i = (plaintext.length()/8) - 1 ; i >= 0; i--){

        charCode = Integer.parseInt((plaintext.substring(i*8, (i*8)+8)) , 2) ;
        c = new Character( (char) charCode).toString();
        System.out.print(c);        // here is where i need something like pt.concat(c) or something like that, I dont really want it printed
    }                               // i just want all of these chars to be put into the string pt 
    System.out.println();
    return pt;
}
```

as you can see in the comments thats what i am talking about, I mean by looking at the API for concat it seems what I am doing is right, but it just wont work!

Thanks if you could explain / show whats wrong!

Comment: First, note that `String pt = null`, so you are getting a null pointer

Comment: Second, you can just set `String pt = "";` and have `pt += c;` at the place of interest. Also, you could skip `c = new Character(...)` and just do this: `pt += "" + (char)charCode;`

Comment: but wouldnt concat just take away nullity?

Comment: thanks man. i would vote that the answer if ya made it one :D worked like a charm!

Comment: Your approach using a string representation of the binary notation of the number is all very fine. If you were going for performance, though, I'd suggest you use [`BigInteger.toByteArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray%28%29). Drop the first byte if it is zero. Then use the remaining bytes to [construct a `String` from these](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20int,%20int,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29). This will be a lot shorter and faster, but more difficult to debug in case anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 4):

1 . You should use StringBuilder to append a char to.

2 . Your code creates a lot of strings: `plaintext.substring(i*8, (i*8)+8))`

Below is the code that fixed both issues.

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    String plaintext = "";

    { // preparing for test
        String input = "abc";
        for (char ch : input.toCharArray()) {
            String charAs8bits = String.format("%8s",
                    String.valueOf(Integer.toBinaryString(ch))).replace(
                    ' ', '0');
            plaintext = charAs8bits + plaintext;
        }
        System.out.println("plaintext = " + plaintext);
    }

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = plaintext.length() - 8; i >= 0; i -= 8) {

        boolean isDigit = Character.isDigit(plaintext.charAt(i)) //
                && Character.isDigit(plaintext.charAt(i + 1)) //
                && Character.isDigit(plaintext.charAt(i + 2)) //
                && Character.isDigit(plaintext.charAt(i + 3)) //
                && Character.isDigit(plaintext.charAt(i + 4)) //
                && Character.isDigit(plaintext.charAt(i + 5)) //
                && Character.isDigit(plaintext.charAt(i + 6)) //
                && Character.isDigit(plaintext.charAt(i + 7)) //
        ;

        if (isDigit) {
            int num = (Character.digit(plaintext.charAt(i), 2) << 7) //
                    + (Character.digit(plaintext.charAt(i + 1), 2) << 6) //
                    + (Character.digit(plaintext.charAt(i + 2), 2) << 5) //
                    + (Character.digit(plaintext.charAt(i + 3), 2) << 4) //
                    + (Character.digit(plaintext.charAt(i + 4), 2) << 3) //
                    + (Character.digit(plaintext.charAt(i + 5), 2) << 2) //
                    + (Character.digit(plaintext.charAt(i + 6), 2) << 1) //
                    + (Character.digit(plaintext.charAt(i + 7), 2)) //
            ;
            output.append((char) num);
        }
    }
    System.out.print("output = " + output);
}
```

Output

```
plaintext = 011000110110001001100001
output = abc
```

**UPD**

I also changed `for` cycle to the view that looks more natural to me - so that `i` points to the "base" index.